# How to toggle between two usernames in a Wix service installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9, serviceinstall

I'm using Wix to install a windows service, but need the option for it to use the LocalSystem account or use an account provided by the user. How should I toggle between a hard coded value and the user value? For the service I have:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Start="auto" 
    Account="[SERVICELOGONUSER]" Password="[SERVICELOGONPASSWORD]" ErrorControl="normal" 
    Interactive="no"/>
```

In the UI I have the property:

```
<Property Id="SERVICELOGONUSER" Value="LocalSystem"/>
```

In a dialog I have:

```
<Control Type="CheckBox" Width="200" Height="25" X="25" Y="75" Id="LocalCheckBox" 
    Property="UseLocalSystem" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="Use LocalSystem Account"/>
<Control Type="Edit" Width="200" Height="15" X="25" Y="115" Id="AccountTextbox" 
    Property="SERVICELOGONUSER">
    <Condition Action="disable">UseLocalSystem = 1</Condition>
    <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[UseLocalSystem <>1]]></Condition
</Control>
```

But this will just display the hard coded value, which the user can edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise making two components with mutually exclusive conditions using your `UseLocalSystem`property, like this:

```
<Component Id="LocalSystem_Service" Guid="{A-GUID}">
  <Condition> UseLocalSystem = 1 </Condition>
  <File Id="SvcFile_Local" Name="Service.exe" Source="Service.exe"/>
  <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Start="auto" 
    Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="User_Service" Guid="{ANOTHER-GUID}">
  <Condition> <![CDATA[UseLocalSystem <>1]]> </Condition>
  <File Id="SvcFile_User" Name="Service.exe" Source="Service.exe" />
  <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Start="auto" 
    Account="[SERVICELOGONUSER]" Password="[SERVICELOGONPASSWORD]" ErrorControl="normal" 
    Interactive="no"/>
</Component>
```

WiX has a limitation where if you need the same file in two places, you need to have a `File` element for it in each place, which is why I have two `File` elements with different `Id`'s.  No worries though, thanks to smart cabbing, WiX toolset will only compress the duplicated content across the Components once.

This way, it won't matter if the user starts to change the `SERVICELOGONUSER` and `SERVICELOGONPASSWORD` and decide to use `LocalSystem` instead.

Hope this helps!